# Имитация нажатия на клавишу по клику на кнопку

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Допустим есть кнопка, при нажатии на которую происходит имитация нажатия клавиши
(например f11).Такое возможно реализовать?

Comment: Имитировать нажатия клавиши с клавиатуры средствами javascript нельзя (конечно мы не берем в расчет selenium и что-то подобное). Однако вполне возможно имитировать нажатие на html-кнопку и.т.д.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Средствами javascript - нет.

Но можно наоборот: перехватить нажатие большинства кнопок на клавиатуре и имитировать любое событие на странице, включая и клики на кнопки.

Answer (score 0):

Возможно создать нужный event, но только лишь внутри своей страницы (а если писать расширение к браузеру - то только лишь внутри браузера, да еще при наличии нужных разрешений у расширения).

И еще, если обработчик "захочет" удостовериться, что event - настоящий, то он сможет это сделать - есть свойство isTrusted у event'ов.